# Should I make my own comparator for pair of two smart pointers in map?

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, compare, smart-pointers

I'm trying to create a template Graph Class, so I need to store Edges somehow. I thought, that   it might be great if I can access EdgeValue by two Node smart pointers. But I don't actually  know, how make it work. Now it's something like this:

```
template <class Node, class EdgeValue>
class Graph
{
 typedef std::shared_ptr < Node > NodePtr;
 std::map < std::pair < NodePtr, NodePtr > , EdgeValue> Edges;
}
```

But I'm pretty sure, it would not work. Should I create compare class or function? Should it be template? And actually, how to compare smart pointers?

Comment: @whozcraig why would shared ptr less be problematic in this case?  It seems a perfect fit to me.

Comment: @Yakk Steven as well agrees. And strangely, now that I think about it, I think you're both correct (still not sure about the `first` side of the key, but the value is a no-brainer, so I'll go with your and Stevens judgement on this and drop both comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `std::pair` has an `operator<` that orders its contents lexographically.

It first sorts by the first element unless the first element is equal: if so, it sorts by the second.

This is sort of like how we sort two letter words.  (`std::tuple` extends this to n-length elements).

`std::shared_ptr` orders itself (the `operator<` is sometimes called the "ordering" operator) by the raw pointer it stores (technically by `std::less` on the pointer it stores, because `<` on pointers is not guaranteed to be very well behaved, while `std::less` is guaranteed to be well behaved).

Between these two, what `<` on `std::pair< std::shared_ptr, std::shared_ptr >` does is sort by the object identity of the first, then the second, element of the `pair`.  Which, in the case of `Node`s in a graph, is often what you want.

If you wanted to order by the *contents* of the `Node`, and not the *identity* of the `Node`, you'd have to provide a comparison function to your `std::map` (or, in theory, override `operator<`, but I wouldn't do that on a two-layer `std` construct on primitive types).